# iOS UIScrollView setScrollEnabled fails

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In iOS5 this works fine:

```
[descriptionWebView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

But in any iOS under 5 it fails with:

```
[UIWebView scrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x791f9e0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView scrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x791f9e0'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't the `setScrollEnabled:` call. It's actually that the `scrollView` of the `UIWebView` wasn't exposed until iOS 5 (which is why it fails on anything else). See the [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for further information.

In previous versions of iOS, you had to [resort to iterating through the subviews](http://blog.andrewpaulsimmons.com/2010/02/controlling-uiscrollview-in-uiwebview.html) of your `UIWebView` to find a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: ahh, interesting, okay thanks.  So I guess I should create a conditional that only applies the setScrollEnabled if ios5.  How do I determine the version in code?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this kind of test which doesn't require you to check which iOS version it is.

```
if([descriptionWebView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]){
    [descriptionWebView.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}
```